# How to add picture box to the picturebox array dynamically

Tags: c#, arrays

Hello I have 20 picture boxes in my form1 which I have positioned. I want to add these 20 picture boxes to my picture box array.   I need help

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Control[] pBoxes = new PictureBox[20];
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        pBoxes[i] = new PictureBox();
                        PBoxes[i] =System.Windows.Find("PictureBox" + i, true);
                    }
    }
```

I tried like this but it did not work

Comment: you will not need to initialize new instance before assigning the control to array item

Answer (score 0):

You're creating *new* PictureBoxes, which is surely not what you intend. Instead, you need to get the *existing* instances of PictureBox in your form. Since they're already added to your form, they probably already exist as a member of `Form1` (especially if you use the designer). Try:

```
var pBoxes = new PictureBox[] {pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, ...};
```

Otherwise you could also do the following to get an array of *all* the `PictureBox` which are *direct children* of `Form1`:

```
var pBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
```

Note though that if the PictureBoxes are inside other containers (e.g. Panels), you will have to recurse through all the containers to get them all.

Comment: sory for my poor programing knowledge . I want use them with index number dinamicly if use var pBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>().ToArray();
 thi method how can use them with index number

Comment: @diego The order you get them in is not guaranteed. I suggest you use the first way to specify exactly which one goes in which index.

Comment: you are true when ı used second way it is not sure picturebox1 is in the pBoxes[1] . how can ı solve this problem without using 1st way . thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get all Picturebox using Linq..

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var pBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>();
}
```